Is this a mistake in speechpy.processing.cmvn?
I was trying to compute the Cepstral mean and variance normalization.
I was told that you take the mean over the features (not frames) of the MFCC vectors and also divide by the standard deviation.
So in PyTorch terms, I would do:
import torch
mfccs = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0]])
# Assume 3 frames, 2 features

mean = torch.mean(mfccs, dim=0)
std = torch.std(mfccs, dim=0)

cmvn = (mfccs - mean) / std
# [[-0.5774,  0.5774],
#  [ 1.1547,  0.5774], 
#  [-0.5774, -1.1547]]

However, the result I got from the speechpy.processig.cmvn was different.
import speechpy
res = speechpy.processing.cmvn(vec=mfccs.numpy(),variance_normalization=True)

# [[-0.7071069,  0.7071068],
#  [ 1.4142134,  0.7071068],
#  [-0.7071069, -1.4142134]]

I inspected the code and noticed something I can't really explain:
Reference:
https://github.com/astorfi/speechpy/blob/master/speechpy/processing.py#L239
    eps = 2**-30
    rows, cols = vec.shape

    # Mean calculation
    norm = np.mean(vec, axis=0)
    norm_vec = np.tile(norm, (rows, 1))

    # Mean subtraction
    mean_subtracted = vec - norm_vec

    # Variance normalization
    if variance_normalization:
        stdev = np.std(mean_subtracted, axis=0)
        stdev_vec = np.tile(stdev, (rows, 1))
        output = mean_subtracted / (stdev_vec + eps)

Why are they taking the standard deviation from mean_subtracted and not vec? I checked both PyTorch and Numpy's docs and both compute the mean directly, so you just have to pass in the raw data without doing something to it before...
Can someone explain?

Two more things: It seems using mean_subtracted and vec will yield the same standard deviation, or very similar. PyTorch does employ something called 'Bessel Correction', whereas Numpy as here does not. So the new question is: Is Bessel correction required for CMVN or not...?
